# Inserting new element into empty JSON object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert data into an empty JSON array, but am having trouble. I'm defining the array in the constructor, then making a couple get requests to the back-end when the page loads, and after getting the response I want to add the new array element to the existing. This is the code I am using:

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            sds: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('/userData', {
          params: {
              user: this.props.auth.user.name
          }
      }).then(res => {
        for(var i=0; i<res.data[0].chemID.split(',').length; i++){
          if(res.data[0].chemID.split(',')[i] != 0){
              axios.get('/chemData', {
              params: {
                id: res.data[0].chemID.split(',')[i]
              }
             //This is where I want to insert the data
            }).then(res => this.sds += ({
              id: i,
              title: res.data[0].chemName,
              selected: false,
              key: 'sds'
            }))
          }          
        }
      })
  }
```

Comment: Where do you want to add which data to?

Comment: `this.state={ sds: [] }` is where I define it.  Then towards the bottom of the code I posted i am doing a `this.sds += ` command (which is wrong), but inside it are the parameters I would like to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+=` doesn't work like that.  Use a spread operator to copy the previous contents of the array, then add the new object in manually -

```
}).then((res) => {
  const newThing = {
    id: i,
    title: res.data[0].chemName,
    selected: false,
    key: 'sds'
  };

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    sds: [...prevState.sds, newThing]
  }))
}
```

You should never try to mutate the state yourself, always use `setState`.  In this case, you can pass a function as the first parameter, which provides the previous state.  That way, you can ensure whatever was in `this.state.sds` is preserved, and your new object is added to that array.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your array by using the `push()` method like this:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        sds: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('/userData', {
      params: {
          user: this.props.auth.user.name
      }
  }).then(res => {
    for(var i=0; i<res.data[0].chemID.split(',').length; i++){
      if(res.data[0].chemID.split(',')[i] != 0){
          axios.get('/chemData', {
          params: {
            id: res.data[0].chemID.split(',')[i]
          }
         //This is where I want to insert the data
        }).then(res => {
          this.state.sds.push({
            id: i,
            title: res.data[0].chemName,
            selected: false,
            key: 'sds'
          })
        })
      }          
    }
  })
 }
```

Comment: `this.sds` does not exist.

Comment: why should it not exist? @larz

Comment: Because it isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: It is defined in the constructor. @larz

Comment: No, `this.state.sds` is defined in the constructor.

Comment: I am blind. Sorry! @larz

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the next example:

```
this.state.sds[this.state.sds.length] = {
          id: i,
          title: res.data[0].chemName,
          selected: false,
          key: 'sds'
        }
```

[Edited]

Like @larz said, you must use the setState method to avoid unexpected result of your code.

```
var newSds = this.stage.sds;
newSds[newSds.length] = {
      id: i,
      title: res.data[0].chemName,
      selected: false,
      key: 'sds'
    };
this.setState({ sds: newSds});
```

You can get more information about the lifecycle in react [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and the "state updates are merged" [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged)

Comment: `this.sds` does not exist.

Comment: NEVER mutate state directly.  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use array.push().
this.state.sds.push(obj);
```

If you are not using react setState method than, you need to refer any state variable using this.state.variableName.

Comment: NEVER mutate state directly.  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state

Comment: Agreed. Then you can go with setState method. (But just be carefull it is Async.)